# UPDATE database with PHP - not working

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-update

My goal is to change the value in the "commission" column from 'open' to 'closed' when I update the table 'status'.I can't seem to get the DB to update. I do not get any errors. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for my submit button:

```
if($result["commissions"]=='open'){
    echo '<form method="post" action="admin_main.php">
    <input name="commissionsC" type="submit" value="Close comissions" />
    </form>';
    }
```

This is the part of my code that is not working:

```
<?php 
include("includes/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['comissionsC'])){ 

$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status");
$row= mysql_fetch_array($res);
$sql="UPDATE status".
"SET commissions = 'closed'".
"WHERE id = 1";
}

?>
```

Comment: That is because you are not executing the query at all.

Comment: You don't seem to execute the UPDATE statement in your code.

Comment: also give a space after `status"` `status "`

Comment: So what I need to add is? (Sorry I am being stupid here)

Comment: Consult my answer @CathrineRydning => http://stackoverflow.com/a/22881505/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE status SET commisions = 'closed' WHERE id = 1");
```

You're not executing your query.

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: You're welcome Cathrine. If my answer did solve it, consider clicking the White (gray outline) tick/checkmark till it turns Green next to my answer to mark as answered. Otherwise, your question will remain in the unanswered category. @CathrineRydning

Answer (score 0):

is it always id number 1 that you want to update? Maybe you have to get the number id for each data :

```
$sql = mysql_query(UPDATE status SET commisions = "closed" WHERE id = 1)
```

Comment: It is always ID number 1 I want :)

Comment: if that so.. 
`WHERE id = 1`
because as I know, if the data is number, it doesn't need use ' '.

Answer (score 0):

Once u get the datas, execute the update query as well

```
$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status");
$row= mysql_fetch_array($res);

$sql = mysql_query(UPDATE status SET commisions = "closed" WHERE id = 1)
```

Comment: Your answer will fail. It should be `$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE status SET commisions = 'closed' WHERE id = '$id'")` if anything. However OP wants it to be `id=1`